# Checking if a word is real

Tags: swift

I want to make sure that a word is real and this is my code:

```
var checker: UITextChecker = UITextChecker()
var range: NSRange = NSRange(location: 0,length: (count(completeWord)))
var misspelledRange: NSRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWordInString(completeWord, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US")
var isRealWord: Bool = misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
if isRealWord {
    println("Correct")
} else {
    println("Not Correct")
}
```

But even if I give it a letter, it says correct. What can I do about that? Basically, I want to remove letters from the corrects.

Comment: Have you tried nonsensical strings? It's possible that the dictionary that it uses counts individual letters as words.

Comment: i'm new to this world and i don't know how to use them. can you explain more please?

Comment: Does it say correct or incorrect if you give it something like "ewkjbefjbegr"?

Comment: thank you very much i solved my problem. i wanted to know if the word exist and for that, i fount "Letterpress" dictionary which was open source and now i check the word with that dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

UITextChecker gives you misspelled words in a sentence. It won't show you wrong letter in a word, but wrong word in the whole text input.

For example:

```
var checker: UITextChecker = UITextChecker()
let string:NSString = "Airplane is gren"
var range: NSRange = NSRange(location: 0,length: string.length)
var misspelledRange: NSRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWordInString(string as String, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US")

misspelledRange.toRange()
```

gives you result as 12..<16, i.e the whole word.

You could use `guessesForWordRange` to get possible correct substitutes:

```
let guesses = checker.guessesForWordRange(misspelledRange, inString: string as String, language: "en_US") as? [String]
```

(returns `["green", "greg", "grep", "grew", "grey", "gran", "grin", "glen", "aren", "oren", "wren"]`)

Comment: yes that's correct but i use it for just detecting a wrong word. i just want to know that a word exists or not and i don't really care about the correct form.